# How to link static library with xcode?

Tags: ios6, ffmpeg, xcode4.2

I have built ffmpeg and link it to my project:

[image]

But when I include libavformat.h , it game me error:

[image]

I want to know what's the settings I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the header files to your header search path in the Build settings and just use `#import "avformat.h"`.

Comment: But when build there are many errors :( , I think I do not need to build ffmpeg again in xcode, I have just built the ffmpeg in command

Comment: @why Did you add the library search path for these libraries to the project too? What are these errors?

Comment: My ffmpeg libraries is at `"$(SRCROOT)/External/output"` and The error image is http://i.imgur.com/QqycSNa.png .

Comment: And `#import "avformat.h"` can not work, I just change to `#import "libavformat.a"`